# mysql does not start on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: php, mysql, database, ubuntu, docker-compose

My website is running on docker container, which is working fine. I am trying to connect my online website's database with admin panel on local host. So I was trying to enable remote access to mysql database server. For that I added some changes in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and on restarting mysql service I've got this error.

I think I have error in starting MYSQL COMMUNITY SERVER.

```
    Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and after running `systemctl status mysql.service`, I get this result

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-02 13:43:29 UTC; 40min ago




Process: 26628 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 13:43:29 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.



-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeate
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'e
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Serv
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

what could be the possible solution?

I have already tried the all other alternative commands to start mysql server but nothing works out.

This is error message I'm getting in my console.

```
    Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Is your MySQL database inside docker container?

Comment: Yes, it's inside the docker container

Comment: I don't yet know why it wouldn't restart. But if you want to permanently change any files in a docker, I think you'd need to build your own docker and have propery `COPY` command or `RUN` command to change it.

Comment: Did you run `journalctl -xe` to see the logs?

Comment: Check your MySQL config file. You can run `mysqld --verbose --help` for more info.

Comment: I have build a docker container already and it's working fine. Mysql within the container is working fine. Do you mean I need to build another container change in existing mysql container?

Comment: yes this is what is get after running 'journalctl -xe'

-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeate
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'e
Oct 02 14:24:59 ip-172-31-31-42 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Serv
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed

Comment: @TaimoorBadar: Would [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit/845473#845473) help?

Comment: If that doesn't work, please run `tail -60 /var/log/mysqld.log` and see if that give you any hint.

Comment: How is this related to PHP, or how is this programming related at all?

Comment: @KoalaYeung as I uninstalled mysql and reinstalled, I don't see /log/mysqld.log

Comment: Do you know where and how you mysqld do its logs?